# Spliting dataframe in multiple dataframes based on reoccuring column value

Tags: pandas, dataframe, split

I recieved a data dump of an pretty old system.
I have a definition.txt file defining the header (column) values of several hundred different tables.
Besides that i also have the corresponding amouth of expX.txt files which include the actual data without any column/header information.
following structure can be found in this file:

```
definition.txt
|  Type | ColumnName | Source   |
|-------|------------|----------|
| 1     | customerID | exp1.txt |
| 2     | name       | NaN      |
| 2     | surname    | NaN      |
| 3     | NaN        | NaN      | ← here i want to split
| 1     | materialID | exp2.txt |
| 2     | weight     | NaN      |
| 2     | dim        | NaN      |
| 3     | NaN        | NaN      | ← here i want to split
| 1     | orderID    | exp3.txt |
...

Wished output:

dataframe1
|  Type | ColumnName | Source   | 
|-------|------------|----------|
| 1     | customerID | exp1.txt |
| 2     | name       | NaN      |
| 2     | surname    | NaN      |

dataframe2
|  Type | ColumnName | Source   | 
|-------|------------|----------|
| 1     | materialID | exp2.txt |
| 2     | weight     | NaN      |
| 2     | dim        | NaN      |
...and so on

then i want to transpose the ColumnName into rows to create a table header.
After that i want to concernate the actual data from the expX.txt file definied on the Source Column.

Desired output for one example:

| CustomerID | name       | surname  | 
|------------|------------|----------|
| 125        | Max        | Cool     | line 1 in exp1.txt
| 126        | Peter      | Smith    | line 3 in exp1.txt
| 127        | Jon        | Doe      | line 3 in exp1.txt
...and so on                           ...
```

The end goal is to create a folder of .csv files representig the different tables. I'am pretty new to Pandas and Python in general and therfore I'm not sure if I use the right toolset or mindeset for the giving challange.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
out = [d for _,d in df.groupby(df['Source'].notna().cumsum())]
```

output:

```
[   Type  ColumnName    Source
 0     1  customerID  exp1.txt
 1     2        name       NaN
 2     2     surname       NaN
 3     3         NaN       NaN,
    Type  ColumnName    Source
 4     1  materialID  exp2.txt
 5     2      weight       NaN
 6     2         dim       NaN
 7     3         NaN       NaN,
    Type ColumnName    Source
 8     1    orderID  exp3.txt]
```

In a loop:

```
for i, (_,d) in enumerate(df.groupby(df['Source'].notna().cumsum()), start=1):
    print(f'--- group {i} ---')
    print(d)
```

output:

```
--- group 1 ---
   Type  ColumnName    Source
0     1  customerID  exp1.txt
1     2        name       NaN
2     2     surname       NaN
3     3         NaN       NaN
--- group 2 ---
   Type  ColumnName    Source
4     1  materialID  exp2.txt
5     2      weight       NaN
6     2         dim       NaN
7     3         NaN       NaN
--- group 3 ---
   Type ColumnName    Source
8     1    orderID  exp3.txt
```